# Redirección PHP para cambiar una variable de sesión

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, sesiones

Tengo que realizar sobre un sitio, una funcionalidad que permite que cuando se ingrese luego de la *URL*, `/+moneda`, se cambie la moneda seleccionada.

Las monedas están asignadas en una variable de sessión de *PHP*, así que pensé en hacer una redirección por `htaccess` hacia una *URL* con un archivo que realice el cambio de moneda y luego redireccionar hacia la *URL* donde se llamó inicialmente sin el `/usd`.

El código que utilizo para realizar la conversión de moneda es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['moneda'])){
    $moneda = $_GET['moneda'];
    $_SESSION['moneda'] = strtoupper($moneda);
}
?>
```

El problema es que no sé cómo luego redirigir hacia el mismo sitio que estaba antes. Hago la redireccion en `.htaccess` con la siguiente línea:

```
Redirect 301 /usd /cambio_moneda.php?moneda="usd"
```

No sé si esta sea la manera adecuada de realizar este tipo de asignaciones de variables de sesión por la *URL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con una regla de reescritura en `.htaccess` de la siguiente manera:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^usd/(.*)$  cambio_moneda.php?moneda=usd&sitio=$1 [L]
```

Luego desde **cambio_moneda.php** lo que hago es tomar ese sitio y hacer una redirección hacia él.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['moneda'])){
    $sitioarederigir = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$_GET['sitio'];
    $moneda = $_GET['moneda'];
    $_SESSION['moneda'] = strtoupper($moneda);
    header("Location: $sitioarederigir");
}
```

Comment: Si tu respuesta es la correcta puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar la redirección con un **header location**:

```
header('Location: origen.php');
```

Comment: Es lo que intento pero no se como saber para que se redirija a la url que estaba antes. Por ejemplo si tengo tienda.com/usd/precios se tendria que reedirigr a tienda.como/precios solo pero habiendo seteado la variable de sesión.

Comment: ¿La duda es cómo identificar de dónde viene y poder regresar? ~ Agrega un ejemplo con el caso de uso más detallado para ver cómo lo resolvemos.